# Close all the figures generated by a loop

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting figures in a loop,  for example:

```
for i in range(100):
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.show()
```

In the loop, I close the current figure, and then it plots the next figure. My question is, because I have too many figures, if I want to quit the whole process in the middle of the plotting, is there a way to do that?

Thanks in advance.

**Update: Finally got what I want:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

#this dict will save the key your pressed
pressed_key = {}

def press(event):
    print('press', event.key)
    if event.key=='q':
        #close the current figure
        plt.close(event.canvas.figure)
        pressed_key['key'] = event.key

for i in range(10):
    #generate x, y for plotting
    x = random.sample(range(1, 100), 20)
    y = random.sample(range(1, 100), 20)

    fig = plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x,y,'o')

    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', press)

    plt.show() 

    #if the pressed key is q, then stop looping through figures
    #note, here must use dict.get('key'), otherwise will have key error
    if pressed_key.get('key') == 'q':
        break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to enable a `break` statement in your for loop. The `break` would be accessed via an `if` statement. For example:

```
for i in range(len(100)):
    if (#some condition):
        break
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.show()
```

The condition you may be looking for could be `i==50` or whatever could implement other variable that you are working with. In your case, maybe it is the moment when there are to many figures, and you would like to close some. That is, you can use

```
if(figure_count >=20):
    close figures && break
```

Comment: Thanks Woody, I want to close the figures interactively, so if I press some button, just close the figures, and break the loop. But now I think I can implement something, to check which button I pressed, and then check it in the if statement.

Comment: @calBear Yeah, that should do the trick! Also, you may want to try to do this with multiple methods. That is, have one method that plots, one method that closes, and one method that speaks to one another. If any of this is useful, feel free to accept this answer so the question can be closed :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand the question. If you want to close all the figures, try `plt.close("all")`.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think this will work, because I want to close it interactively. But thanks anyway!